# Is there a way to export automatically (all) zones/boxes as jpg/png/images?

Tags: ocr, abbyy, finereader

I would like to export a piece from each page of a pdf document in order to create a shorter document (to facilitate manual pre-treatments, actually).
I've already "boxed"/"zoned" them with Abbyy FineReader (12).

Would anyone know how to export these boxes/zones to image files (separate or not) ?
Ctrl + Shift + C may yet copy one zone, but I can't manage to copy every zones, nor to export the zones as images instead of OCRized text.

Thanks for your help !

edit 1 [to explicit my purpose]:

there's what I would like to export (from hundred of pages, boxing zones in Abbyy FineReader or with another tool which could spare me copying and pasting hundreds of times !) : https://www.noelshack.com/2019-19-5-1557492079-source.png

... what I would like to get at the end : https://www.noelshack.com/2019-19-5-1557492079-cible.png

edit 2 :
the adequate term in English interface for FineReader is "Area", not "zone".
"Copy area as image" (ctrl+shift+c) is possible one by one. I'd like to "catch/batch 'em all" !

edit 3 :
For the time being, I cheated : using the "crop-the-page" function of a PDF reader, then saving them as .jpg images (and compilating these "crops" under LaTeX).
If anyone has ever another idea, I'd be glad to take it !